# Package.json & background-networking Error - Setup VSCode Debugger for Electron App

Tags: debugging, electron, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am going off of this YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuZIeJ0ljgo

He did a good job  explaining, but I am still getting different errors as I go through the steps he did.

Configuration: “Launch Program”

Electron Pop Up Error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Uncaught Exception:
Error: Can't find package.json
    at findPackageJson (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:19:11)
    at findPackageJson (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:29:10)
    at findPackageJson (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:29:10)
    at findPackageJson (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:29:10)
    at findPackageJson (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:29:10)
    at main (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:44:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:61:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:63:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

Configuration: “Debug”

Electron Pop Up Error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/dev/electron-app/--disable-background-networking'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at init (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-compile/lib/config-parser.js:294:16)
    at main (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:58:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:61:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/electron-app/node_modules/electron-prebuilt-compile/lib/es6-init.js:63:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

Here is my configuration, .vscode/launch.json:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",

            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/index.js",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "runtimeArgs": [
              "--enable-logging"
            ]
        },
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Debug",
          "skipFiles": [
              "<node_internals>/**"
          ],
          "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/index.js",
          "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
          "runtimeArgs": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "--enable-logging",
            "--remote-debuggingh-port=9222"
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I having the same problem and finally found a trick that worked for me.

1. Close any electron.exe related process. If you are on Windows base system you can open the task manager and look for the eletron processes or run this command:

`taskkill /im electron.exe /f`

2. Unistall electron npm library from your project:

   `npm uninstall electron`
3. Install electron again:

   `npm install electron@latest -D`